# MS SQL: SELECT field1, field2 from [table] where field2 NOT IN ('val1', val2') when field1 = 'value2'

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, subquery

I am currently having troubles with filtering my SQL records. I need something like what it results in the following concept:

**I wanted to results of some records based on the results of another field in the same table. Say, like the following:**

```
SELECT [Field1], [field2] 
FROM [table]
WHERE [Field1] IN ('value1', 'value2')
--from 'value2' i need to filter or remove some records 
WHERE [field2] NOT IN ('val1','val2') When [Field1] is 'value2'
```

I've been spending lots of hours on this I still can't do the right stuff.
I'd appreciate immediate help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting with the top answer (@Siyual's), you can optimize it to lessen maintenance :

```
SELECT  [Field1], [field2] 
FROM    [table]
WHERE   ([Field1] = 'value2' AND [field2] NOT IN ('val1','val2'))
OR      ([Field1] = 'value1')
```

Using `[Field1] = 'value1'` or `[Field1] in('value1', 'value3', 'value...', 'valueN')` means that whenever a new value is put into [Field1], your query break. You would be much better to replace with with `[Field1]!='value2'`, giving you :

```
SELECT  [Field1], [field2] 
FROM    [table]
WHERE   ([Field1] = 'value2' AND [field2] NOT IN ('val1','val2'))
OR      ([Field1] != 'value2')
```

From there, you can also apply logic operators to realize that you're saying `WHERE (A && B) || !A`, in this case, there is no difference between a XOR or a OR, which means it's equivalent to `WHERE (!A)||B`, which gives you :

```
SELECT  [Field1], [field2] 
FROM    [table]
WHERE   ([Field1] != 'value2') OR [field2] NOT IN ('val1','val2'))
```

Comment: actually the top answer was the closest one. I'm just figuring out what else i am missing.

Comment: I reworded the whole post to explain my point better. Basically, I'm doing the same thing as @Siyual, so as long as you don't add any new data, both of our queries should do exactly the same.

Comment: thanks for this! i get what you're suggesting but it doesn't give me the results I want.

what I wanted to get was to use some of the results from the first filter to my next filter. like what's 

where [field1] IN (SELECT DISTINCT category from anotherTable)

--the result of that first filter will be the base of the second filter..so, if the categories include "value2", i will have to filter the records where field1 is value 2 exclude display of those records having "val1" and "val2" so that the only records that will be filtered with that are those records that is equal to value2 in [field1]

Answer (score 1):

Small bit of logic for two fields.

```
   SELECT [Field1], [field2] 
     FROM [table]
    WHERE [Field1] IN ('value 1' , ... ) -- Other non value 2 values
       OR (Field1 = 'Value 2' AND [field2] NOT IN ('val1','val2'))
```

Comment: this actually helps other than " [field1] IN ('value1, 'value2') " is actually like  this..

[field1] IN  (SELECT DISTINCT [field] from [TABLE2])

so value 2 is actually a part of another query..

Comment: Moraler, its a good idea to think of the logic of how you want to filter. If you can write it out just as a simple sentence then you can generate your where clause.

Comment: I actually did. I still can't figure it out. LOL!

it's this one.

Comment: I actually did. I still can't figure it out. LOL!

it goes like this...

get field 1 and field2 from the table where field1 has this values from another table and not display some records that has val1 and val2 if the record from another table is value2

Answer (score 1):

You will need to separate the logic for each condition.

```
SELECT  [Field1], [field2] 
FROM    [table]
WHERE   ([Field1] = 'value2' AND [field2] NOT IN ('val1','val2'))
OR      ([Field1] = 'value1')
```

Answer (score 1):

not clear what you really want.

but My Guess

```
SELECT [Field1], [field2] FROM [table]
WHERE [Field1] in ('value1', 'value2')
and [field2] !=(case 
when [Field1]='value1' THEN 'val1'
when [Field1]='value2' THEN 'val2'

.
.
.
End)
```